Circular Breakout Game: time or collisions needed to reach nth layer
Shower thoughts...
A tiny ball starts inside a unit circle, surrounded by fixed concentric circles of increasing integer radius length. So it starts in is the 0-th "level".
The ball moves in a straight line and bounces without friction, loss of momentum, or gravity.

Upon collision, an arc length s is removed from that circle (let's say, 1 radian) similar to the game of breakout where a brick is removed once the ball collides with it.
Because there is always some removal and collision, the ball must eventually reach any level.

Question: How long does it take for the ball to reach (collide with) layer n as a function of the angle and starting point?
Observe for example that the nth layer would be reached after n/2 collisions if we start at the origin and the ball bounces back and forth between diametrically opposed sides of each circle.
It should be possible to make a color map showing the stopping time for each starting point.
I am also wondering if due to symmetry the starting angle shouldn't matter.
Any pointers to relevant readings or similar experiments would be appreciated.

I would suggest simulation, as I suspect the answer is neither simple nor smooth.   The starting position and angle will matter.  There is some rotational symmetry, so if you rotate the starting position round the centre and the starting angle by the same amount, you get the same answer. You ask "How long?", but will get different types of answers depending on whether this is distance (or time) or whether it is numbers of collisions, but you could consider looking at starting positions on the non-negative $x$-axis and the starting angle vertically straight up.

added a simulation tag
